# ASP .net application finds local resource files in Web Development server, but not local IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, resx

When I run the application using the Visual Studio Web Development Server it works fine. However when I run it using local IIS I get the following error:

Any ideas? Thanks!!

The resource class for this page was not found.  Please check if the resource file exists and try again. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The resource class for this page was not found.  Please check if the resource file exists and try again.

Source Error:

Line 81:         private void PopulateLanguageList()
Line 82:         {
Line 83:             DropDownListLanguage.Items[0].Text = (string)HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(
Line 84:                     "\Default.aspx", SelectLanguage, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
Line 85:         }

Stack Trace:

[InvalidOperationException: The resource class for this page was not found.  Please check if the resource file exists and try again.]
   System.Web.Compilation.LocalResXResourceProvider.CreateResourceManager() +4038050
   System.Web.Compilation.BaseResXResourceProvider.EnsureResourceManager() +23
   System.Web.Compilation.BaseResXResourceProvider.GetObject(String resourceKey, CultureInfo culture) +24
   System.Web.Compilation.ResourceExpressionBuilder.GetResourceObject(IResourceProvider resourceProvider, String resourceKey, CultureInfo culture, Type objType, String propName) +32
   System.Web.HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(String virtualPath, String resourceKey, CultureInfo culture) +56
   APPortal.Login.PopulateLanguageList() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\APPortal\Default.aspx.cs:83
   APPortal.Login.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\APPortal\Default.aspx.cs:20
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +132
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2428

Comment: Where do your DLLs live? /bin or in GAC?

Comment: In /bin. Do you think the dlls are an issue? If so, why would it work in the web developer server and not IIS?

Comment: What happens if you configure Visual Studio to use IIS? Does it work then?

Comment: i replaced the local resources with global resources and this seemed to solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

i replaced the local resources with global resources and this seemed to solve my problem!